# how can i setAttribute to display a thumnail beautifully in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript file, and declare a variable,

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', (entry.snippet.thumbnails ? entry.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url : ''));
```

its shows a big thumbnail, how can i adjust the value of this thumbnail to look it beautifull, like in youtube ?

Comment: you might need to learn css

Comment: There's no defined attribute can make it beautifull.. you have to adjust it using CSS

Comment: how can i done this, i am using youtube API to display the search results, how can i modify thumbnail like smaller, larger etc, ?

Comment: use CSS like others have stated...